# How to parse a string with custom format

Tags: c#, parsing

I want to parse a string with the following format:

```
"(null|L-D,S,D)C(\d){1,2}(H|D|S|M)"
```

- First group: containing nothing, or first letter of a day in spanish (L, M, X, J, V, S, D), or comma separated list of the same letters or a group of consecutive days (i.e: J-D meaning J, V, S, D).
- "C", meaning "every"
- Second group: a number between 0 and 99.
- Third group: an H (hours), D (days), S (weeks) or M (Months)

As an example:

- "C12H" will be translated to "every 12 hours"
- "LC6S" will be translated to "mondays every 6 weeks"
- "L,X,VC6H" will be translated to "mondays, wednesdays and fridays every 6 hours"
- "L-VC12H" will be translated to "from mondays to fridays every 12 hours"
- "J-LC12H" should not be parsed, but thinking it twice, it could meaning "from thursday to mondays".

As for now I have this code inside a class:

```
    static public void InterpretInterval(string Interval)
    {
        // Format: (null|L-D,S,D)C(\d{1,2})(H|D|S|M)

        string pattern1 = @"^(([LMXJVSD][-,]?){0,7})C(\d{1,2})(H|D|S|M)\s*$";
        Regex rex = new Regex(pattern1, RegexOptions.Compiled);
        string msg = "";

        Match m = rex.Match(Interval);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Número de grupos: {0}", m.Groups.Count.ToString()));
            List<string> days = SplitDays(m.Groups[1].Value);
            string temp = "";
            if (m.Groups[4].Value == "H")
                temp = "Hours";
            else if (m.Groups[4].Value == "D")
                temp = "Days";
            else if (m.Groups[4].Value == "S")
                temp = "Weeks";
            else if (m.Groups[4].Value == "M")
                temp = "Months";
            else
                temp = "Error";

            msg = string.Format("Original: {0}\n\rDaysOfWeek: {1}\n\rFrequency: {2} {3}",
                                Interval, string.Join(',', days.ToArray()), m.Groups[3].Value, temp);
        }
        else
        {
            msg = "Could not parse.";
        }

        MessageBox.Show(msg);

        return;
    }

    static List<string> SplitDays(string value)
    {
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();

        var CommaGroups = value.Split(',');
        if (CommaGroups[0] == "")
        {
            // By the moment just handled this way i.e: "C24H" is more frequent than "C8S" so right now I translate to "all days" every "number" "hours|days|weeks|months"
            temp.Add("from L to D");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var group in CommaGroups)
            {
                if (group.Length == 1)
                {
                    temp.Add(group);
                    continue;
                }
                var DashGroup = group.Split("-");
                if (DashGroup.Length == 2)
                {
                    temp.Add(string.Format("de {0} a {1}", (string)DashGroup[0], (string)DashGroup[1]));
                    continue;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Days of week parsing error.");
                return new List<string>();
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

I am sure it could be improved, just wondering how. I am using spanish letters, but I have in mind to give support to other languages, so the algorithm should not rely on the number of characters as it is doing now.

It is written in C#, but any useful answers in other programming languages will be welcome as well.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This would be better suited to code review stackexchange, here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the pattern below:

```
^(?:[LMXJVSD](?:[,-][LMXJVSD])*)?C[1-9][0-9]?[HDSM]$
```

Here:

```
 ^                  - beginning of the string (anchor)
 (?: .. )?          - optional day part 
 [LMXJVSD]          - day L ... D
 (?:[,-][LMXJVSD])* - optional continuation , or - followed by day
 C                  - C
 [1-9]              - digit 1..9 (I doubt if 0 can start the number)
 [0-9]              - optional second digit 0..9  
 [HDSM]             - any letter of H, D, S, M
 $                  - end of the string
```

[Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/ZKhniQ/1)

If you want to work with groups, you can name them:

```
 ^(?<days>[LMXJVSD](?:[,-][LMXJVSD])*)?C(?<count>[1-9][0-9])?(?<kind>[HDSM])$
```

And then

```
...
if (m.Success) {
  string days = m.Groups["days"].Value;
  int count = int.Parse(m.Groups["count"].Value);
  string kind = m.Groups["kind"].Value;

  //TODO: Here we can check if days, count and kind construct a valid combination  
}
...
```

Comment: Nice suggest that handles pattern better than my first option, just added capturing groups and remove first noncapturing group: @"^([LMXJVSD](?:[,-][LMXJVSD])*)?C([1-9][0-9]?)([HDSM])\s*$". You are right with 0 number. I have never used the naming groups, nice of you to note it. I am looking for a solution to handle better the "days" part and oriented to multilanguage (regex is stick to one language). An array with the name of the days (I could load the language version from resources), transform into numbers, expand the ranges, and use it.

Comment: @raululm: as for *multilanguage* I doubt if it's ever possible in general case: each culture has its own pattern(s), e.g. it will be `Пн-Пт` in Russian for `Monday - Friday`; moreover, Russian doesn't have any tail part like `6S` at all; you have to write it as "6 weeks" or "2 months" otherwise you'll be misunderstood.

Comment: Yes, that is why I found challenging this parsing. I am going to post the code as I have right now, supporting some multilanguage.

Answer (score 0):

After refactoring a little bit my previous code:

1. Use slight variation of the suggestion of Dmitry Bychenko, which has improved mine first approach.
2. Change the output of the parser function to be an object with an array of booleans encoding the seven days, the interval and the units of the interval, in order to use in the rest of the program.
3. Add a list to hold the abbreviations of the week day names, in order to use it in the parsing (now is harcoded, in the future would be loaded dynamicaly). I must do the same with the units of interval.

   ```
    public enum IntervalUnits
    {
        Undefined,
        Hours,
        Days,
        Weeks,
        Months,
        Years
    }

    public class InterpretedPosology
    {
        public string days = "";
        public int interval = 0;
        public IntervalUnits units = IntervalUnits.Undefined;
    }

    static public InterpretedPosology InterpretInterval(string Interval)
    {
        // Format: (null|L-D,S,D)(C)([1-30])(H|D|S|M)
        string pattern1 = @"^(\w*(?:[,-]\w*)*)?C([1-9][0-9]?)([HDSM])\s*$";
        Regex rex = new Regex(pattern1, RegexOptions.Compiled);

        InterpretedPosology temp = new InterpretedPosology();

        Match m = rex.Match(Interval);
        if (m.Success)
        {
           temp.days = string.Join(",", ParseDays(m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray());

           if (!int.TryParse(m.Groups[2].Value, out temp.interval))
           {
                temp.interval = 0;
                temp.units = IntervalUnits.Undefined;
                temp.days = "";
                return temp;
           }

           if (m.Groups[3].Value == "H")
               temp.units = IntervalUnits.Hours;
           else if (m.Groups[3].Value == "D")
               temp.units = IntervalUnits.Days;
           else if (m.Groups[3].Value == "S")
               temp.units = IntervalUnits.Weeks;
           else if (m.Groups[3].Value == "M")
               temp.units = IntervalUnits.Months;
           else if (m.Groups[3].Value == "A")
               temp.units = IntervalUnits.Years;
           else
               temp.units = IntervalUnits.Undefined;

        }

        return temp;
    }

    static bool[] ParseDays(string value)
    {
        //string[] DayLetters = { "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S", "D" }; // Spanish
        string[] DayLetters = { "MON", "TUES", "WEDS", "THURS", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN" }; // English
        bool[] Days = new bool[7];

        for(int i = 0; i < DayLetters.Length; ++i)
            Days[i] = false;

        var CommaGroups = value.Split(',');
        if (CommaGroups[0] == "")
            for (int i = 0; i < DayLetters.Length; ++i)
                Days[i] = true;
        else
        {
            foreach (var group in CommaGroups)
            {
                if (!group.Contains('-'))
                {
                    Days[Array.IndexOf(DayLetters, group)] = true;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    var DashGroup = group.Split("-");
                    if (DashGroup.Length == 2)
                    {
                        int a = Array.IndexOf(DayLetters, DashGroup[0]),
                            b = Array.IndexOf(DayLetters, DashGroup[1]);
                        if (a <= b)
                            for(int i = a; i <= b; ++i)
                                Days[i] = true;
                        else
                        {
                            for (int i = a; i < 7; ++i)
                                Days[i] = true;
                            for(int i = 0; i <= b; ++i)
                                Days[i] = true;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < DayLetters.Length; ++i)
                    Days[i] = false;
                return Days;
            }
        }

        return Days;
    }

    public void Main() {
        /*string[] str = {
            "L,X-VC6S", "C6S", "L,M,J,V,S-DC12H", "J,S-D,MC24H", "D-MC8H" };*/
        string[] str = {
            "MON,WEDS-FRIC6S", "C6S", "MON,TUES,THURS,FRI,SAT-SUNC12H", "THURS,SAT-SUN,TUESC24H", "SUN-TUESC8H" };
        foreach (string str2 in str)
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Original: {0}\n\r{1}",
                str2, InterpretInterval(str2).ToString()));
   }
   ```

Should cope with edge cases (case sensitive, among others, but this is the idea I have right now) and error checking.